# Dynamic retrieving the information from Mysql base on the button action

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I have a set of button which there text(Button text) is based on the department name that the user create in the database. So the Department Button get populated when the page is loaded.

Now my problem is when the Department button is pressed I what the get the name of the department from the button using `.getText()` method and use the Text that i get from that method as argument that I can pass in SQL where clause to call all the item name under that department.

```
// Actions for the menu button
@FXML

void menu_1(ActionEvent event) {
    Object MenuText = event.getSource();
    Button Menu = null;
    String deptName = "";

    if( Menu != null)
        deptName = Menu.getText();

    Conn = MySQLConnect.ConnectDB();
    Map<Integer, Object> menuItemIdMap =new HashMap<>();
    menuItemIdMap.put(1,Item1);
    menuItemIdMap.put(2,Item2);
    menuItemIdMap.put(3,Item3);
    menuItemIdMap.put(4,Item4);
    menuItemIdMap.put(5,Item5);
    menuItemIdMap.put(6,Item6);
    menuItemIdMap.put(7,Item7);
    menuItemIdMap.put(8,Item8);
    menuItemIdMap.put(9,Item9);
    menuItemIdMap.put(10,Item10);

    String Sql= "SELECT PluIName FROM xpresspos.pluitems  where (PluIDept = '@deptName') ";

    try {
        pst = Conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        // Object menu;
        int index = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            index++;
            String pluName = rs.getString("PluIName");

            Button item= (Button) menuItemIdMap.get(index);
            item.setText(pluName);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to create a dynamic where clause that will solve the problem?

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions please! and don't you mix swing into fx apps

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [prepared statement parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
String sql = "SELECT PluIName FROM xpresspos.pluitems WHERE PluIDept = ?"
pst = Conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, deptName);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem

First I change the menu declaration to:
''
Button Menu =(Button)event.getSource();
''
I remove the if statement and I applied the SQL fix that @Job Curtis show in the above and it works thanks